# Can't retrieve html content of a webpage with Python requests

Tags: curl, python-requests, wget

Trying to get content from a website: www.arrow.com but my program gets freezing. I cannot retrieve any response at all.

I have used curl, wget and the same issue. I get:

```
<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a HREF="https://www.arrow.com/en/products/search/">here</a></body>
```

I did get the response using POSTMAN, where I realized that the response is encoded with gzip. In the website, many people suggest to add some headers to solve that issue but I have had no success so far.

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.arrow.com/en/products/search/'
params = {'q': 'ISOW7841FDWER'}
headers = {
        'Accept-Encoding': "gzip,x-gzip,deflate,sdch,compress",
        'Accept-Content': 'gzip',
        'HTTP-Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Accept-Language': "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    }
r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print(r.url)
print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have all those items in `headers`, but you do need to spoof User-Agent otherwise the site won't respond.

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.arrow.com/en/products/search'
params = {'q': 'ISOW7841FDWER'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5'}
r = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
print(r.url)
print(r.text)
```